# Hw: Python error when testing a function which takes two parameters computes them and returns a list

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have created a function which takes two parameters computes them and returns a list with each element set to the sum of the parameter n and the corresponding value in the input list. Here is my code for the function:

```
    def add_n_all(L,n):
        listx = map(lambda x:x + n, L)
        return listx
```

The code to test my function looks like this:

```
    def testmap_1(self):
        L = [2, 3, 4]
        n = 2
        L2 = map.add_n_all(L,n)
        self.assertListAlmostEqual(L2, [4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4])

    def testmap_1(self):
        L = [2, 3, 4]
        n = 2
        L2 = map.add_n_all(L,n)
        self.assertListAlmostEqual(L2, [3, 1, 6, 4, 8, 6])
```

However when I run my test I keep getting this error. I've tried to change the variables around but it doesn't seem to work so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

### FAIL: testmap_1 (**main**.TestCases)

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "map_tests.py", line 33, in testmap_1
        self.assertListAlmostEqual(L2, [3, 1, 6, 4, 8, 6])
     File "map_tests.py", line 7, in assertListAlmostEqual
        self.assertEqual(len(l1), len(l2))
     AssertionError: 3 != 6
```

---

```
   Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

   FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Your tests have the same names. Which one failed?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be *6* returned values when the list going into the function has only got 3?

Comment: I'm not sure what the relationship is between `L` and your expected lists you are testing with. Adding `2` to each element in `L` you'd expect a list with `[4, 5, 6]`, not `[3, 1, 6, 4, 8, 6]`.

Comment: Insert `print(L2)` before the assert so that you can see what the function is doing, then it will be clear what's wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's because OP copied the test case but forgot to change `L`. It should be `[1, 4, 6]`.

Comment: Use `L.insert(index, value)` to solve your problem. `map` will not be useful, just use a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I run my test I keep getting this error.

[`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AssertionError) in Python is raised when a test (or in other words an [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) fails.

in your `assertListAlmostEqual` there is a check on the length of input and output lists.

```
 self.assertEqual(len(l1), len(l2))
```

In your test case the input

```
L = [2, 3, 4]
```

is of length 3.

and length of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function's output list will be same as the length of its input.  So, comparing the length of your output `L2` (which is `3`) with the length of `[3, 1, 6, 4, 8, 6]` (which is `6`) would obviously fail the assertion.

So, in your test case you need to rectify what you compare your `L2` with.

Changing

```
self.assertListAlmostEqual(L2, [3, 1, 6, 4, 8, 6])
```

to

```
self.assertListAlmostEqual(L2, [4, 5, 6])
```

passes the test (unless your intention is to test negative cases, in which case you need to use [`assertNotEqual`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNotEqual)).

OR

If your intention is to get an output list with `+n` on each element and also the corresponding element from the list then you can do one of the following (**not writing the code...this is your HW rt...**):

```
def add_n_all(L,n):
    # Consturct an empty list, which will be used to return as the output of this function
    # for each element in the list
        # do .extend() with [element+n, element] on the list initialized earlier for the purpose of this function return

    # return the output list
```

OR

```
def add_n_all(L,n):
    # good luck figuring out this list comprehension
    return [item for sublist in [[x+n, x] for x in L] for item in sublist]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm mistaken by my teacher's instructions but from what's written in the instructions it seems that the function's output should be the sum of the parameter n and the corresponding value in the input list therefore would there be two outputs for every input? Or is not possible to have an input list of 3 which returns a list of 6, or could I possibly be mistaken by the instructions? Sorry I'm still a beginner at Python so I'm trying to get through the basics.

Comment: ah..understood.  You can have a function with a list of size 3 as input and list of size 6 as output but `map()` is not that function.  Updated my answer (intentionally gave you hints but not the actual solution)

Comment: Okay great thanks for your help, I had to write three functions and one of them had to use map() but now i see it won't work for this function thanks!

Comment: Sure.  And if my answer or any other answer helped you resolve or bail out of the problem please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't add length, so you are comparing a list with 3 elements(`L2`) to a list with 6 elements, which are obviously not equal.